# XBee module lockup/freeze

Tags: raspberry-pi, xbee

I am using Xbee series 2 modules to handle communications between my home automation modules. As my base station, I am using Raspberry PI with Xbee coordinator attached to it.

It all seems to be working well, however, after around a week of flawless functionality, the xbee module just freezes. It does not respond to anything and appears disconnected. The only way I can bring it back to life is to remove it from the socket and put back (or power-off the whole board).

I've tried both using an addon board to inteface the xbee directly with Raspi's serial port and using a USB-based XBee adapter. In both cases, the problem is the same - after few days the xbee module just stops responding.

I suppose I could detect this state and device a way to perform the reset using GPIO but it "should" work as it is.

Anyone experiencing similar issues?

Comment: Did you flash the latest firmware to the XBee?

Comment: yes, flashed&configured from scratch

Comment: What firmware release was it flashed up to? Does it hang WITHOUT the other end broadcasting to it? That is, could it be a config issue on the remote end.

Comment: I have the same issue, there is definitely a bug in the xbee 2 non pro modules, I have 3 pieces which tend to get their DIN frozen until power cycle.
So far my only solution is to invest one digital pin to reset the xbee in such cases.

Comment: that really is a shame - have you tried getting in touch with Digi? My issue is slightly less prominent when I decrease the amount of traffic going through, so I've deprecated Xbee for new devices and shrank the existing network to only contain one legacy device, which seems to be working..

Comment: @RonJ. - the freeze is much more likely if other end is broadcasting. From my perspective, it should not matter what the other end throws at it - it should not lockup when it receives something it does not expect!